# Globally set withoutGlobalScopes() Laravel

Tags: laravel, database, scope

Can I somehow set off/on all global scopes for all queries? I know I can do `User::withoutGlobalScopes()->...` but this is called for each query and I'd like to achieve something like:

```
DB::withoutGlobalScopes(); //turn off
//multiple queries go here
DB::withGlobalScoper(); //turn on
```

Comment: You can create your own query macro for desired functionality.